# cannot get the value of isset($_POST['value'])

Tags: php

I have 2 php pages. 1st php page is the following:

```
<?php
  //code...
  if(isset($_POST['value'])== true && empty($_POST['value']) == false){
    echo"<a href='search_form_all_2.php'>See more results for </a>"; 
} ?>
```

the second page is the "search_form_all_2.php".

```
<?php

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

$name_and_surname = explode(" ", "$value ");

$name = $name_and_surname[0];

$surname = $name_and_surname[1]; 

$query = mysql_query(" SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users 
   WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE
   '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%')  ");

while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $surname = $run['surname'];
    $name = $run['name'];
    echo"$surname $name  "; 
}
?>
```

I want to make the $value in "search_form_all_2.php" to get the value of the first page that I have in `if(isset($_POST['value'])== true && empty($_POST['value']) == false)` of 1st page. How can I do this because when running "search_form_all_2.php" I get an erros message:Notice: Undefined index: value

Comment: store the values in a session, or pass them as query string parameters in the `<a href="...">` link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GET in this case. POST values are only send when a form is submited.

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])== true && empty($_POST['value']) == false){
    echo "<a href='search_form_all_2.php?value=".urlencode($_POST['value'])."'>See more results for </a>";
```

then on second page you retrieve the GET value

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);
```

Be careful, GET values are visible to the user. They are part of a URL. Don't send confidential information.

Another way is to save the value in a COOKIE or in SESSION variable.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $_POST['value']);
$value  = $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

BTW `empty()` always returns boolean value and it already checks if the variable is set, so you only need:

```
if(!empty($_POST['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st page, you can pass an argument in the url... example:

```
echo "<a href='search_form_all_2.php?s=".urlencode($_POST['value'])."'>See more results for </a>";
```

Then, in your 2nd page, you can call the argument... example:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);
```

PS: You shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions. Instead learn mysqli at the very least or PDO.

Comment: Note: Typically you'd want your search results page to be link-able.. IE: User A can copy/paste the URL and send it to User B. Therefore your search form should perform a GET request versus a POST request, then you can access `$_GET['s']`... much like how search engines work (Google, Yahoo, Etc).

Answer (score 0):

On `search_form_all_2.php` you can't access the data value because when you click a link, it is a GET request, not a POST request. I suggest you look up the differences.

However, if you use this to spit out the link:

```
echo"<a href='search_form_all_2.php?more={$_POST['value']}'>See more results for </a>";
```

You can then retrieve it with $_GET or $_REQUEST (if you want to be able to use GET or POST) on page 2:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value']);
```

Comment: Does the name you're passing in actually have a space in it? If not, you could get an error. You should be checking that sort of thing. Look up defensive programming.